# Sugar CRM New Module

Tags: php, sugarcrm

I am using sugarCRM open source for my own purpose. 
I want to develop the new module with the existing code and i have downloaded the zip files from the internet for this.
I want to know, 
Is there any possible to put the downloaded code directly in the folder?
I did this,using "module loader" but i need to achieve through the direct path.

And one more thing is, when i put the new files into the existing files, what are all the folders will affect?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use Module Loader in the Admin panel?

```
-> Admin
-> Module Loader /index.php?module=Administration&action=UpgradeWiza rd&view=module
-> Browse to 'install from local file'
-> hit button 'browse'
-> select the file I want to upload (ZIP)
-> hit 'open' 
-> hit 'upload'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check the  manifest.php in zip

In this file there are all the parameters which are required to load the module in the system.

like.. version for which the module can get loaded, path of the files from the zip files will be loaded or replaced if any in the system.

Cheers!!!